# Issue with adding a layout in Fragment Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am working on FragmentTabs. When I try to show the following layout in one of the tabs, I don't see the button on the screen. I can see the button if I don't use tabs.The activity's layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/simple_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/new_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="New fragment">
        <requestFocus />
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

The FragmentTabs code is as follows:

```
package com.example.tabswithfragments;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

/**
 * @author mwho
 * 
 */
public class TabsFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();
    private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

    private class TabInfo {
        private String tag;
        private Class<? extends Fragment> clss;
        private Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String tag, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz, Bundle args) {
            this.tag = tag;
            this.clss = clazz;
            this.args = args;
        }
    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;
        /**
         * @param context
         */
        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }
        /**
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
         */
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Step 1: Inflate layout
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs_layout);
        // Step 2: Setup TabHost
        initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); // set the
                                                                                // tab
                                                                                // as
                                                                                // per
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // saved
                                                                                // state
        }
    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); // save the tab
                                                                // selected
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /**
     * Step 2: Setup TabHost
     */
    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1",
                        MainActivity.CountingFragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        TabsFragmentActivity
                .addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2")
                        .setIndicator("Tab 2"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2",
                        ListActivity.FavList.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

        // Default to first tab
        this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
        //
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * @param activity
     * @param tabHost
     * @param tabSpec
     * @param clss
     * @param args
     */
    private static void addTab(TabsFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state. If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
            ft.commit();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
     */
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                }
            }
            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                            newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }

            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

}
```

Counting fragment class is as follows:

```
package com.example.tabswithfragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    int mStackLevel = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_stack);

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_fragment);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addFragmentToStack();
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Do first time initialization -- add initial fragment.
            Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();
        } else {
            mStackLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("level");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("level", mStackLevel);
    }


    void addFragmentToStack() {
        mStackLevel++;

        // Instantiate a new fragment.
        Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);

        // Add the fragment to the activity, pushing this transaction
        // on to the back stack.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }



    public static class CountingFragment extends Fragment {
        int mNum;

        /**
         * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
         * as an argument.
         */
        static CountingFragment newInstance(int num) {
            CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();

            // Supply num input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        /**
         * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        }

        /**
         * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
         * instance number.
         */
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
            View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
            tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help me please.

Comment: What does your CountingFragment class look like?

Comment: I have added the CountingFragment class.

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have asked for the FavList class (since CountingFragment does not seem to use the layout xml you show above), is it the second tab not displaying correctly?

Comment: @Rookie I used `Support v4` Library to create `TabPager` using fragment. Full demo is here. https://github.com/Abhan/AndroidDemo/tree/master/ICSStyleTabViewPager

Answer (score 1):

In the main activity layout just use this code, the reason why I remove the button view is that we can create another layout that we can put the button there. Just imagine that the `simple_fragment` in the main.xml will be replaced or another xml or view will be added to it using the with_button.xml

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/simple_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**hello_world.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<!--Other Views -->
 <Button android:id="@+id/new_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="New fragment">

 </Button>

</LinearLayout >
```

**CountingFragment Fragment**

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
            View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
          tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));

                Button btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.new_fragment);

         btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("Button","Clicked");  
           }});

            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `android:layout_weight="0"`? I don't think it is a good practice. In LinearLayout, android:layout_weight is use to divide layout into pieces and the number means how many pieces it will take. For example, if you use two `android:layout_weight="1"`, then each of the subview will be hold 50%(`1/(1+1)`) of the whole layout. However, in your case, you use 1:0, which means 1 will contains whole layout and 0 gets nothing. So the 0 part will not show at all. I think you should use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout in your case.

Answer (score 1):

layout_weight for your button should not be zero.